# How long should interpolation last in multiplayer game?

Tags: multiplayer, interpolation, extrapolation

I'm making a multiplayer game. Server is sending update packets 20x per second, that contain players positions, velocities and other important data. I want to interpolate between current and updated positions, so that it feels smooth. I know linear interpolation formula.

My question is: how long should such an interpolation last? Is it 50ms, 2 frames or what?

Comment: You should interpolate until you receive an update packet, no?

Comment: But you have to know exact interpolation duration in order to be able to do it

Comment: But you __do__ know the duration. Its the same duration as you use for sending packets, what else would you use? Everything else makes no sense.

Comment: so you are saying I should use a value 1/20 secs? What about a ping value, like half a ping or something?

Comment: so you're saying, if you have a - lets say - 20ms ping, you'd interpolate in 10ms. This means, every 50ms the enemy would walk for 10ms and then stay for 40ms. If you have a 200ms ping you'd interpolate in 100ms, meanwhile two new packets arrived while you walked with half the normal speed.

Comment: I don't know, that's why I'm asking. However, we could override last interpolation with new interpolation so that there won't be so much desync as you said. Should I maybe use a server's tick rate(1/20) with a ping value somehow?

Comment: Not for interpolation, no. What you can do is wait for a few packets before you even start to let the player move, but you _should_ use the normal packet-send-rate as interpolation duration to get the correct smooth movement.

Comment: @tkausl I will try. Should I interpolate velocities too?

Comment: Wait, what? No, velocities are not interpolated. They are not even used for interpolation but you could use them for extrapolation if you'd like to implement this.